# Tridion Sites 10 - Experience Space extensibility Documentation and Community Updates

Tags: gui-extensions, tridion-sites, experience-space

Tridion Sites 10 - Experience Space extensibility Documentation and Community Updates

Extensibility features allow you all the liberty that you need ,With extensions Experience Space offers you several ways to interact with external content and applications from within Tridion Sites

Items in the primary navigation (e.g., you could create a custom dashboard and embed it in the application)

Extensions for custom URLs in the editor that can implement a value picker to even retrieve data from an
external system

Custom data to show in columns in Content Explorer lists

Panels inside the explorer

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to Tridion Sites 10 - Experience Space extensibility - Primary Navigation Customize [link](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/techweblog/posts/tridion-sites-10---experience-space-extensibility---primary-navigation)

Tridion Sites 10 - Experience Space extensibility - Content Editor External Data Select  [link](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/techweblog/posts/tridion-sites-10---experience-space-extensibility---content-editor-external-data-select)

Tridion Sites 10 - UI Extensibility Rich Text Editor [link](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/techweblog/posts/tridion-sites-10---ui-extensibility-rich-text-editor)

Comment: I was trying to run it locally but ran it problem with proxy. I raised a separate question here : https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/22198/gui-extensions-for-experience-space

Comment: Rahul , thanks for your comment , i also updated the other https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/22198/gui-extensions-for-experience-space , will keep you posted