# GUI extensions for Experience Space - Not working on Local

Tags: gui-extensions, tridion-sites, experience-space, sites-10

Trying to Implement Experience GUI extensions for Experience Space using below documentation: https://docs.rws.com/1099765/1068407/tridion-sites-10-main-documentation/gui-extensions-for-experience-space

https://github.com/RWS/tridion-sites-extensions-examples

while running project locally i get below error on browser:

Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/ui/

In Terminal logs i see :
e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/ui/ to https://development.tridion.sdlproducts.com/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Using rws sites as saas and using SDLCXC credentials for logins.

NOTE: if i try to proxy other sites like facebook or google instead of cme, they work!

I tried multiple things by tweaking devServer.js if saas need more changes but was not able to run it locally.

Comment: Rahul , We will review and update you , also i would suggest you create a support ticket and may be will be able to share some more details on how to make it work

Comment: Rahul, I assume you are using access management  please confirm

Comment: @AnandNS yes! we are using access management

Comment: I get this error message on access management screen :
An error occurred.
Invalid redirect_uri
Check the logs for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try the following from your local and let me know if its working

Step 1) access the access management URL  , go to Applications ->  double click Tridion Sites Experience Space

Step 2) Click on Edit and Add the following URL

- http://localhost:3000/ui/signin-oidc
- http://domainname:3000/ui/signin-oidc  ( domainname of the CMS )

Step 3)  Restart the Access Management Apppool

Step 4) install visual studio code on the CMS server  go to the extension   example : \simple-action-addon\hello-action open the package.json add http://domainname  to the target ( CMS domain URL)

Step 6)  run ( npm i )  and run npm run dev , it will load the http://localhost:3000/ui/ with the extensions displayed successfully.

Hope it works for you !!

Comment: it works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the confirmation , please reach out to tridion stackexchange if you have any further questions related to extensions and anything else we are happy to address your questions